# Is it possible to intercept network traffic using selenium

Tags: c#, .net, selenium-webdriver, firefox, automation

Is there any library or a way to intercept POST response body while using Selenium in C#? What I mean is the library similar to selenium-wire in python that allows one to see the traffic and get the response messages. So far I have tried a method such as this: [Catching Network Traffic With Selenium C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68582545/catching-network-traffic-with-selenium-c-sharp)
but it doesn't output any network traffic or response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way! It took me a long time to figure out, lots of research, and some help with a couple of devs I work with. I'll try and explain it as best as possible with code examples:

So, to intercept the incoming network traffic, this is how I'm doing it (as I need the full request URL for my solution):

```
        IDevTools devTools = (IDevTools)driver;
        DevToolsSession session = devTools.GetDevToolsSession();
        var domains = session.GetVersionSpecificDomains<DevToolsSessionDomains>();
        await domains.Network.Enable(new EnableCommandSettings());
        domains.Network.Session.DevToolsEventReceived += Session_DevToolsEventReceived;
```

Then, you'll need to click the button/do whatever function you need to do that you need the response for. In my case, its clicking a button to generate a report. Then, you need the 'Session_DevToolsEvenReceived' which is:

```
        static void Session_DevToolsEventReceived(object? sender, DevToolsEventReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            _url ??= e.EventData["documentURL"]?.ToString();
        }
```

This will get the request URL and store it into a string. Then, the way I'm doing it is to have the code that calls the api in a separate class, but calling it like so, so that the response is stored in a variable:

```
var result = await Call.GetData(x, x, x, _url)
```

You'll need to make sure the test method this is used in is a public async task as opposed to a void. The 'x' in my example are numbers which allows access to the api (userId, accountId, and organisationId), so why I've had to mark them as 'x'. Now this next snippet is the code that then calls the api to get the response, with the request URL being passed to it. This is in a separate class file in my solution

```
namespace ApiCall
{
    public class Call
    {
        private static HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        public Call()
        {}
        public static async Task<string> GetData(int userId, int accountId, int organisationId, string requestId)
        {
            var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, requestId);           
            request.Headers.Add("Accept", "text/plain");
            request.Headers.Add("UserId", userId.ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("AccountId", accountId.ToString());
            request.Headers.Add("OrganisationId", organisationId.ToString());
            var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

I appreciate this is lengthy, but I hope it gives some insight, and helps you achieve what you need. Its not yet wildly documented on I found! Please let me know how you get on!